# Is that possible to stream mms,ASX,RTSP stream on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, stream, core-audio, asx

I am developing one music streaming application.

I can stream mp3 using a method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384900/streaming-audio-from-server-to-iphone). Does anybody know approach to stream other formats(ASX, RTSP or mms) using Core Audio or other framework.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the FFmpeg library to stream MMS and RTSP streams. Have a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445918/is-it-possible-to-decode-an-mmswma2-stream-using-audio-units-on-the-iphone/8136244#8136244) to see how you can use FFmpeg in combination with AudioQueue.

Answer (score 9):

mms, ASX, and RTSP are historically somewhat proprietary protocols (by microsoft and real, in particular), so you may have trouble finding an official apple implementation.

There's a LGPL implementation of the mms protocol here: https://launchpad.net/libmms
Or you can get the documentation for the protocol from microsoft here: http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/5/E/95EF66AF-9026-4BB0-A41D-A4F81802D92C/%5BMS-MMSP%5D.pdf

ASX is just a metadata format in XML; you'd use it to get a mms or http URL to stream from. The official reference for it is on microsoft's site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb249663.aspx

RTSP has an LGPL implementation here: http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/
It's a standard protocol ([RFC 2326](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2326) and [RFC 3550](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550)) but is apparently often used with proprietary extensions such as Real's RDT transport, so again it might be easier to just use a library if you're able.

Answer (score 0):

Try the free FStream iPhone app http://www.sourcemac.com/?page=fstream that can handle mms, asf, wmv, asx and ogg

Answer (score 0):

FStream is good for audio. You can also use Streamer for video streaming. It is a good app except that it is not friendly at all. Type the URI mms://server/ in your favorites. Then click on it. You will find a button that says: "Pause". Click that again to read: "Unpause". Then wait for 10-15 seconds, the video will start streaming after that. Make sure that you choose a URI that you know works for sure.

Comment: Its not the answer for the question asked..!