# Streaming audio to iphone (with options play/pause)?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio-streaming

Is there any third party frameworks for streaming audio form network server/ web server?
I need to implement audio streaming functionality in my new project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not third party. You need to use [Apple's HTTP Live Streaming](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/) framework if you want to be approved in the app store to stream over 3G.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how can we play audio through RTSP streaming, I googled it a lot but nothing understandable came up :(

Comment: I Googled for "iPhone RTSP" and there are a couple of things that come up, most of which say it's very difficult to do since RTSP isn't really made for mobile devices that switch between cell towers and network types frequently. Remember, RTSP is a Real® technology, so you shouldn't expect full support in an Apple product.

Comment: Check out this SO question, too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750501/is-that-possible-to-stream-mms-asx-rtsp-stream-on-iphone

Comment: Thanks Marc,i am also getting same results only, so decided i will go for http streaming.

Comment: It's not true that you need to use Live Streaming to be approved in the app store for 3G. You just need to make sure your data usage when streaming over 3G is less than 5MB over 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The framework StreamingKit from Thong Nguyen works very well for streaming audio 
https://github.com/tumtumtum/StreamingKit